# How to create another standard user account in os?

Tags: user

I want to create another user account for my family to access computer how to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the System Settings application, navigate to **User Accouns** (down right icon) . On the User Accouns section there is a smal **+** sign into the lower left corner, hit it, autrhorize yourself as an Administrator and you will get a window with settings for the new account, Standart type should be the default one.